# If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name

Tags: soql, master-detail

I'm having trouble putting together a SOQL query.

Basically i have a parent object (Opportunity), with multiple child objects (Borrower_Pair__c). The relationship from the child to parent is created through a master-detail field (Owner_Application__c) on the child (Borrower_Pair__c).

The goal is to get the ids of the all the child objects.

Here is what i have so far...

```
List<sObject> borrPairIds = [SELECT Id FROM Borrower_Pair__c WHERE Owner_Application__c.Id = :oppId];
```

Where :oppId is the Id of the opportunity. However when i run this, i get the error in the title.

The full error is

```
Didn't understand relationship 'Owner_Application__c' in field path. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names. (31:37)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `Owner_Application__c.Id` to `Owner_Application__c`. Alternatively, you could use `Owner_Application__r.Id` but you should avoid the crossobject reference as it is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

`Owner_Application__c` itself represents the `Id` of Opportunity to which your child object is related to.

You will need to simply use `Owner_Application__c` in your SOQL:

```
SELECT Id FROM Borrower_Pair__c WHERE Owner_Application__c = :oppId;
```